# why dont accept the validation at laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have some problem with validation `thl1` when I insert two numbers 
it
accept it but it have `min:10` , when  I use `'thl1'=> required|min:10` without `numeric` 
it doesn't accept 2 or more  numbers but accept the letters, in database 
thl1 is `varchar(191)`

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request){
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:25|min:3|alpha',
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:25|min:3|alpha', 
        'username' => 'required|max:25|min:3|alpha_dash|unique:users,username,'.Auth::user()->id,
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:55|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id,
        'country' => 'required|min:3|alpha|max:30',
        'city' => 'required|min:3|alpha|max:30',
        'thl1' => 'required|min:10|numeric',
        'thl2' => 'min:10|numeric|nullable',
    ]);
}
```

validation.php

```
'thl1' => [
    'min' => 'To Τηλέφωνο 1  πρέπει να περιέχει τουλάχιστον 10 χαρακτήρες. ',
    'numeric' => 'To Τηλέφωνο 1  πρέπει να περιέχει μόνο αριθμούς. ',
    'required' => 'Το Τηλέφωνο 1 είναι υποχρεωτικό',
],

'thl2' => [
    'min' => 'To Τηλέφωνο 2  πρέπει να περιέχει τουλάχιστον 10 χαρακτήρες. ',
    'numeric' => 'To Τηλέφωνο 2  πρέπει να περιέχει μόνο αριθμούς. ',
]
```

Comment: what is your rejection values in `thl1` column?

Answer (score 0):

`min:10`, without `numeric`, will mean a minimum of ten *characters*, as it's treated as a string. The string `10` is two characters, so it won't be accepted. `the zero-y-est zero that ever zeroed` will be accepted, as it's over ten characters.

Adding the `numeric` rule tells Laravel to only accept numeric values, and that the value must be greater than or equal to the *numeric* value 10.

Comment: i understand this but i want to accept it 10 numbers , not 1,or,2 or 5 for examlpe i want to accept 6988888888 and not 6988 how can make this?   thl1' => 'required|min:10|numeric', is not work for me

Comment: Use the `regex` rule type.